# Can i create multiple global style sheet for user change?

Tags: react-native

I'm the beginner of react-native.

I'm going to provide change global font size function in my app.

User could change the font size in setting page, them the whole app font size will be adjusted.

After doing some research, it seems can't do it. So my idea now is create multiple global style sheet and apply it base on the user setting saved in storage.

But I found that it seems not work, because after create global style sheet, it need to import at the beginning of the app page.

How can I apply change the app global style or font size in react-native?

Comment: Are you trying to implement something like themes ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want take a look at [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook, it will give you a good way to handle app global style, suck as light or dark theme, your case, font is also not a problem.

Another way is using react-redux, create a global state for your font, and all your component will listen to the font value stored in the store.

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep it abstract. How I would do it: create and assign a theme for your app where you define classes with different font-sizes etc. Save the preferences as classes in the async storage. After loading the up retrieve saved preferences from async storage and set those to your components as classes. Job done.